# Math.js Error: Cannot convert "abc" to a number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, math.js

I have a math.js function in react. What it does is evaluate formulas using the values from the variables, e.g.:

```
var variables = {'A': 1, 'B': 2}
var formula = 'A > 0 or B < 5'

math.evaluate(formula, variables) // this will return true
```

But when comparing strings, it returns the following error,

> Error: Cannot convert "abc" to a number

```
var variables = {'A': 'abc'}
var formula = 'A == "abc"'

math.evaluate(formula, variables) // this will return Error: Cannot convert "abc" to a number
```

Can anyone guide me on how I should do this? what I need is that the variables can evaluate on string and numbers both, Thanks. Any question similar to this will be appreciated as well. I tried to search, but couldn't get much.

I have tried the following, it doesn't override the function:
https://github.com/josdejong/mathjs/issues/1051#issuecomment-369930811

**UPDATE**
This is what I am trying to do:

```
formula = ' A >= 2 and B == "year" '
variables = { A: 23, B: 'year' }
```

```
import { evaluate } from 'mathjs'

const MATH_EVAL = (formula, variables)=> {
  var result = evaluate(formula, variables)
  return result
}
export default MATH_EVAL
```

Comment: I think your problem lies in the fact that the first example has variables A and B that are both numbers, and the second example has a single variable A that is a string. It seems that `evaluate` expects variables to be numbers, not strings.

Comment: @Pyromonk yes, I do know that, but is there a way to compare strings as well as numbers?

Comment: You should perhaps reword your question to indicate that.

Comment: Uodated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/josdejong/mathjs/issues/1557

The answer to the above question is on the above mentioned link. It says and I quote:

> I've created an example for this: [examples/advanced/custom_relational_functions.js](https://github.com/josdejong/mathjs/blob/c74a736ff987a279ba9ed3d73eb9870d85494acc/examples/advanced/custom_relational_functions.js). Can you have a look at that and see if it makes sense and solves your issue?
>
> The main difference is that the created functions don't update their dependencies anymore when you replace an existing function with a new one. I have to give that some more thought, maybe we can make this work when working with a mathjs instance (instead of pure functions).

Answer (score 0):

I am a little bit confused as this works using the issuecomment? Maybe a typo?

```js
var variables = {'A': 'abc'}
var formula = 'A == "abc"'
math.import({
  equal: function (a, b) { return a === b } 
}, {override: true})
console.log(math.evaluate(formula, variables))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/6.0.2/math.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have tried it, the app is on react maybe an issue with that i suppose? I have opened up an issue https://github.com/josdejong/mathjs/issues/1557

The owner as well said it doesnt seem to be working in this case.